# Firebase ember fire adapter fails in validation rules for parent child relationships

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

Firebase allows you to have validation rules ensuring that particular children exist for any given node. For example:

```
{
  "rules" : {
    "posts" : {
      "$postsID" : {
        ".validate" : "newData.hasChildren(['title','body','authors'])",
        ...
```

Above, if we try to create a node at /posts/ without giving it a title, body, or authors, Firebase will reject our request.

However, the updateRecord function in the [EmberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire) adapter is using separate promises to save relationships and the model itself.

So, in the example above, when we save a new post, [EmberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire) might attempt to write to /posts//authors/ before it writes to /posts//title and /posts//body. In that case, our validation rules will fail.

There are a couple of solutions that come to mind

1. Patch the ember fire adapter to write all the updates to a node using a single request instead of using multiple requests.
2. Patch the adapter to use [transactions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) and then we can use the validations.

I am wondering if there are any other solutions that does not involve patching the adapter

PS - This is posted on github issues for Firebase as well - https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/304

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are correct. At the moment, `hasMany` relationship links are saved in a series of separate requests to the server. This will cause issue with security rules that require there to be at least one `hasMany` link.

Lets keep discussing this in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/304). It is possible we will change the behavior of the adapter.